# Data Path Routing or Switching for AFE circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, encoder, decoder, digital-isolator

Currently i am making the PCB (for analog front end) for the digitization of some sensors(electro-chemical and photo-ionizations).

To simply the things this sensors are giving output in Milli volt(photo-ionizations sensors) and uA current(electro-chemical sensors).

I have BOTH(independent) the circuit ready which are taking input and giving digital output.
(one circuit is based on the trans-impedance amplifier while another is based on the operational amplifier)
Now the thing is i want to make a single channel PCB which works for both the sensor(one at a time) at same input terminal. All the sensors have the 3 leads.
Probably i required the programmable switch (decoder demultiplexer) so that MCU can switch the routing path of that 3 leads when user gives input to the MCU. (when sensor(uA output) is connected then he will press the switch-A and vice versa for the sensor(mv output) with switch-B).

Please let me know suggestion that it will work or not for that lower inputs (i mean very low current and voltage).Any suggestion of the IC will be great help.

**Added below details**
lead terminal of sensor Info :-
 - 1:- GND 
 - 2:- Current Output/Voltage Output
 - 3:- Not Used in most of cases.

Range of mills volt :- 1mv to 500mv
Current output sensor are just floating photo sensors.

Speed for switching is not concern i can adjust with lower speed also. And isolation is also not required for ground of both sensor.(however isolation will not be in picture as at a time only any one sensor get connected)

Thanks,
Bhautik

Added Photo to simplify things more. As from picture "solution should select the Path A or Path B" based on the input signal to it.
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want to switch the low level signals.  Is your voltage range from 0 to Xmv, or +/-X mv?  Is the current just a floating photo sensor?  You say there are there 3 terminals?  What is each of the terminals?  Are any of them ground?  Are you trying to isolate the grounds between the sensors?

Comment: What accuracy must you achieve? And what speed? How fast to settle after switching, so the ADC can accurately perform quantization?

Comment: Hi crj11 and analogsystemrf , thanks for your comments i added some details in the summary of question after "Added below details" bold text line.i hope that clicks or please ask if more information needed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is a [high isolation reed relay.](https://www.google.com/search?q=high%20isolation%20reed%20relays)  A "Form C" or SPDT relay would allow you to select between two sources.  You could perhaps use a [low leakage analog switch like the ADG779](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG779.pdf), but because analog switches are not passive devices, you could have higher leakage and offset issues.  However, analog switches are generally less expensive.

The relays have > 1000 GOhm isolation.  Remember that at pA leakage levels, you need to worry about issues like surface contamination on the PCB potentially increasing the leakage.

Comment: Hi crj11, Thanks for your answer. But here ,Source will be one only(either with output as current or voltage). i required to select different path for both output as same amplifier circuit will not work for both sensor. to simplify things i added one image in the summary.